# Tamil Font in Yii2 Application

Tags: php, fonts, yii2

How to display `Tamil font` in `Yii2` advance template?

When I try to do that, it is showing me question marks : `??????`. An in the Yii2 application, it is Displaying `not displaying Yii2-mpdf export`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Improved your question even if it is still unclear what is the error you get....

Answer (score 0):

my code: 
1) upload "MyFont.ttf" into /mpdf/ttfonts 
2) in /mpdf/config_fonts.php , inside $this->fontdata array, add your:

```
"my_custom_fonttt" => array( 
                    'R' => 'MyFont.ttf',            //Regular- REQUIRED
                    'I' => "MyFont-Oblique.ttf",    //Italic - OPTIONAL
                    'B' => "MyFont-Bold.ttf",       //Bold   - OPTIONAL
                    ),
```

3) then, wherever you execute your custom script, use my_custom_fonttt in css:

```
<?php
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$texttt= '
    <html><head><style>
    body {font-family: "my_custom_fonttt";}
    </style></head>
    <body>My SAMPLE TEXTTTTT </body>
    </html>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML("$texttt");
$mpdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__).'/new_created_file.pdf','F');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add font to your css file by @font-face. And add option **cssFile** to config your mPDF object.

Simple:

```
$pdf = new Pdf([
    ...
    'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
    ...
]);
```

If don't help read [docs](http://demos.krajee.com/site/mpdf).